# Why Gradle is not running dependent tasks

Tags: node.js, gradle, npm

I have the following build.gradle in an angular project:

```
plugins {
  id 'war'
}

task npmInstall(type:Exec)
  commandLine "npm.cmd", "install", "@angular/cli"
}

task npmBuild(type: Exec) {
   commandLine "npm.cmd", "run", "build"
}

task war.dependsOn(npmInstall, npmBuild)
```

but when I run the war task the npmBuild and npmInstall are not ran

Comment: have you tried simple debugging? what Gradle version are you using? I think `npmInstall` and `npmBuild` wont work as expected, try with `gradle npmBuild` to check.

Answer (score 0):

As of Gradle 7.5, your build script doesn't compile anymore and raises the following error

```
> Could not create task ':task ':war''.
   > The task name 'task ':war'' must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |].
```

The problem is with the `task` keyword in statement `task war.dependsOn(npmInstall, npmBuild)`. To instruct Gradle to execute `npmInstall` and `npmBuild` before executing the `war` task do this:

```
war.configure {
  dependsOn npmInstall, npmBuild
}
```

You may also use `war.dependsOn npmInstall, npmBuild` to configure the dependency.